# Convert Image (JPG,BMP,GIF) to SVG

Tags: c#, image-processing, svg

Anyone know a tool that actually works (I tried several, but none works), with support for color images. If some know how to implement this, or any component that makes (C#), I would be grateful.

Thanks for any help

---

The program below works, however, leaves all the files in black and white.

[Total Vectorize](http://www.coolutils.com/TotalVectorize)

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? JPG etc. are bitmap formats, while SVG is a vector format. There is a fundamental difference, and conversion is a complex process.

Comment: Define "works." What are you trying to convert? Obviously a photograph won't work.

Comment: @Pekka Just wanted to convert a simple picture, even simpler, with 3 / 4 colors and small for the SVG format

Comment: @Simon Brown I converted the images, but they are all black on white. This, unfortunately not for me. No, the image is far from the complexity of a photograph.

Comment: don't do this automatically if you can avoid it. Try one of the vectorization programs recommended below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Converting bitmap graphics to vector graphics (for example, PNG to SVG) is a definitively non-trivial task, with no straightforward solution. Doing it the other way round - vector to bitmap graphics - is of course a simple process of rendering, and that's how things are usually done if you want both formats.

At its core, such a conversion requires complex and error-prone algorithms that analyse patterns in images. More complicated images will simply be impossible to decompose into vector graphics. The technical explanation is based on the fact that the [information entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_entropy#Relationship_to_thermodynamic_entropy) of bitmap representations is guaranteed to be higher than that of vector representations, which means there is always uncertainity in reversing the well-defined process of vector graphics rendering.

The best program widely available for your task is likely to be [**Vector Magic**](http://vectormagic.com/home) (shareware). If that doesn't do the job for you, it's not likely anything will, though of course you'll probably need a lot of tweaking for good results.

Comment: Wouldn't the trivial solution be to map each pixel of the input file to a square in the corresponding (relative) position with the same color?  It would look like crap when scaled, just like a scaled jpeg would, but it would work, no?

Comment: Sure, but you're still effectively using a bitmap format, just masking it under the guise of a vector format. It certainly doesn't make the image freely-scalable, as I'm sure you realise.

Comment: In addition, this would make the image many, many times the size of its gif or jpg counterpart, as each pixel would get a full node in the vector image. Not a really viable solution.

Comment: It seems that **Vector Magic** is no longer shareware. :(  They have a Trialware; but for long term they want $$.

Answer (score 5):

This process is know as vectorization. It is process of converting bitmap image to vector image. There are many tools, including free, that can do this, for example http://inkscape.org/

But the result of such processing is far from perfection.

Hope this helps. Maybe I got your answer wrong, and you need to convert bitmap image to vector programmaticaly, or you're asking how to embed bitmap image into SVG image.

Comment: Sure, though Inkscape doesn't do a particularly good job of it from what I know.

Comment: Gotta be better than an all-black result.

Answer (score 2):

SVG is Scalable *Vector* Graphics, which effectively means drawing lines.  The format is inimical to displaying an image, which is fundamentally a matrix of pixels.  Lines can easily be converted to pixels, but displaying pixels as lines (or dots) is wildly inefficient and not really *scalable*.  The alternative of attempting to *discover* lines within a pixilated image is fraught with peril.

If what you want is simply to recover a non-scalable image in SVG format, you might find a tool to do that.  But since scaling is what SVG is *for*, I wanted to be sure you understood why you might have difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

[Open Clip Art](http://www.openclipart.org/wiki/index.php/SVG_Tools)

This link includes tools, libraries web based options and other tantalizing bits.

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

One of the best open source vectorisers is potrace.  It comes as a [standalone tool for the command line](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/). Or if you prefer a GUI, it is included as part of [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).  Both are available for multiple OSs.

Answer (score 0):

[Vector Magic](http://vectormagic.com/home) is by far the best tool that I know for this task. However, you can only apply vectorization for a limited number of images, after that you have to subscribe or buy a license for the desktop edition.

Answer (score 0):

I have a proprietary vector drawing program that saves bitmaps, jpegs, GIFs, and Pngs to SVG format. This is the output svg text file for a specific bitmap.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg width="1024px" height="768px" version="1.1"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <image xlink:href="C:\RedWind\Bitmaps\PrayerChild.bmp" 
                         x="20" y="20" width="384" height="428"/>
    </svg>
```

SVG files are pure text files. You can create them with windows notepad, MS Word, or any text file creator.
You can copy this text, place it in notepad, save it to a file with ".SVG" file extension and then copy the filename i.e. "c:\bitmaps\MyBitmap.SVG" and paste it in the navigation area of your browser and it will produce the SVG file in the browser. Be sure to substitute the location of your bitmap in place of the "C:\RedWind\Bitmaps\PrayerChild.bmp." Also substitue your bitmap's position and width/height data at x, y, width, height. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the [PicSvg website](http://picsvg.com/) to work pretty well (for a free tool) on simple bitmap images.

[(Non)Disclaimer: I'm not affiliated with them in any way, just found it when I needed a quick tool for a project idea I was working on..]

Answer (score 0):

You may just embed the bitmap within SVG as base64 encoded using the **image** tag

```html
<svg>
<image xlink:href="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
</svg>
```

just like the **img** tag of html

```html
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```