# Sourcecode to convert JPG (bitmap) to SVG (vector)?

Tags: php, python, svg, jpeg

I'm looking for source code that converts JPG bitmap images to SVG.
I will a stand-alone solution I can put and launch online.

I found Potrace but it works with BMP input.

Comment: Just [convert from JPG to BMP](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3AStackoverflow.com+convert+JPG+to+BMP).  There are libraries for this in various languages.  You didn't mention which you're using.

Comment: I'm using PHP/MySQL and Python.

Comment: You can use ImageMagick to convert to BMP format first, either on the command line, or via a PHP/Python API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072621/convert-image-jpg-bmp-gif-to-svg

Comment: I realise that Potrace may not work online, just with Unix console. Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to all of you, here's my process to convert JPG bitmap to SVG:

- imagemagick to convert JPG to BMP
- a python file using potrace via subprocess to convert BMP to SVG
- mkbitmap is also useful to keep the max of details during the vectorization.